# HAproxy not routing from virtual IP

Tags: haproxy, virtual-ip-address, keepalived

I am currently trying to configure HAProxy to route between two servers using a virtual IP.

For testing I created two instances, 172.16.4.130 and 172.16.4.131. I am then creating a virtual IP address of 172.16.4.99, using keepalived which will be bridging the two servers. Both of these servers are running apache2, which is hosting a simple index.html landing page for testing. All of the above is running.

When I go to 172.16.4.99, the page does not load, nor am I redirected to either one of the index.html pages. I can however, ping this IP address. I feel like this is a simple configuration issue, and since I am not very experienced with HAproxy, I would like some assistance. Below are my haproxy.cfg files, as well as keepalived.

```
global
    log 127.0.0.1   local0
    log 127.0.0.1   local1 notice
    #log loghost    local0 info
    maxconn 4096
    #debug
    #quiet
    user haproxy
    group haproxy

defaults
    log     global
    mode    http
    option  httplog
    option  dontlognull
    retries 3
    option redispatch
    maxconn 2000
    contimeout      5000
    clitimeout      50000
    srvtimeout      50000

listen webfarm 172.16.4.99:80
   mode http
   stats enable
   stats auth user:password
   balance roundrobin
   cookie JSESSIONID prefix
   option httpclose
   option forwardfor
   option httpchk HEAD /check.txt HTTP/1.0
   server webA 172.16.4.130:8080 cookie A check
   server webB 172.16.4.131:8080 cookie B check
```

keepalived.conf on 172.16.4.130

```
vrrp_script chk_haproxy {           # Requires keepalived-1.1.13
    script "killall -0 haproxy"     # cheaper than pidof
    interval 2                      # check every 2 seconds
    weight 2                        # add 2 points of prio if OK
}

vrrp_instance VI_1 {
    interface eth0
    state MASTER
    virtual_router_id 51
    priority 101                    # 101 on master, 100 on backup
    virtual_ipaddress {
        172.16.4.99
    }
    track_script {
        chk_haproxy
    }
}
```

keepalived.conf on 172.16.4.131:

```
vrrp_script chk_haproxy {           # Requires keepalived-1.1.13
    script "killall -0 haproxy"     # cheaper than pidof
    interval 2                      # check every 2 seconds
    weight 2                        # add 2 points of prio if OK
}

vrrp_instance VI_1 {
    interface eth0
    state MASTER
    virtual_router_id 51
    priority 100                    # 101 on master, 100 on backup
    virtual_ipaddress {
        172.16.4.99
    }
    track_script {
        chk_haproxy
    }
}
```

Comment: State should be 'BACKUP' instead of 'MASTER' on the backup server (172.16.4.131)

Answer (score 1):

I have made similar structure to balancing transactions for the MYSQL. I can reach the MYSQL server behind virtual IP. Maybe my config helps you.

https://serverfault.com/questions/857241/haproxy-dont-balancing-requests-between-nodes-of-galera-cluster

It would be greate if it helps you.